# Writing variable's content to a variable file inside a variable-directory

Tags: bash

Let's say I write the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
TEXT="hello"
DIR="test"
FILE="bla.txt"
echo $TEXT > $DIR/$FILE
```

When running it, I get the following error:

```
test.sh: line 5: test/bla.txt: No such file or directory
```

But if change the last line to:

```
echo $TEXT > $FILE
```

I don't get the error.

I know I can work around it and do:

```
FILE_TO_WRITE_TO=$DIR/$FILE
echo $TEXT > $FILE_TO_WRITE_TO
```

But I don't understand why does the error occur in the first place.

Comment: Try this: `mkdir "$DIR"`

Comment: Tried it on my system and it works perfectly fine

Comment: Never mind, I have no idea why it didn't work right before I asked the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command gives `No such file or directory` error because `test` directory doesn't exist or `Not a directory` if it is not a directory.

```
echo "hello" > test/bla.txt
```

To create the directory if necessary, and error management.

```
mkdir -p "$DIR" || { echo "failed to mkdir $DIR"; exit 1;}
echo "$TEXT" > "$DIR/$FILE" || { echo "failed to open $DIR/$FILE for writting"; exit 1;}
```